# Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

i m trying to add this query into my code in laravel.
it runs smoothly in phpmyadmin or with mysql command line but enable to get anything but this syntax error.

my query :

```
$query_sql=" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE F as( 
                        SELECT * from (
                            select M.* ,M2.idA from (
                                        SELECT  o.id , o_n.id_n as idD from o ,o_n where FIND_WILD_IN_SET(o.id,o_n.id_o)
                                        and o_n.id_n IN ({$start_n_string})
                                    ) M  
                            JOIN ( SELECT  o.id , o_n.id_n as idA from o,o_n where FIND_WILD_IN_SET(o.id,o_n.id_o)
                                    and o_n.id_n IN ({$end_n_string})
                            ) M2 on M.id = M2.id GROUP by id
                        ) x
                    );


SELECT o.* from o
                where o.id IN ( 
                    select id_offre from o_rv join F on F.id = o_rv.id_offre 
                    where find_in_set(idD,o_rv.id_n]) < find_in_set(idA,os_rv.id_n)
                    )";
            
        $list_pot_r=DB::select($query_sql);
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select o.* from
> o

***NOTE:***

- Tried 'strict' -> false
- Using DB::select();
- DB::unprepared() the only that doesnt return any error but it doesnt
  return the result neither only a (TRUE)

***EDIT***

when i remove the last statment i get this :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
> other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using
> PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever
> going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
> the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

Comment: How are you adding this query in laravel? can provide code?

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... using DB::select($query);

Comment: Then check if you are putting proper quotes around query.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh.....i did check i even took the query the exception provided and it worked in phpmyadmin / mysql command line

Comment: Please post you laravel code of DB::select.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you env don't allow multiple query in a single statement so due the fact your temp table seems not update  try using a dynamic query instead of a create temp table

```
SELECT o.* 
from o
where o.id IN ( 
    select id_offre from o_rv 
    join (SELECT * from (
                    select M.* ,M2.idA from (
                                SELECT  o.id , o_n.id_n as idD from o ,o_n where FIND_WILD_IN_SET(o.id,o_n.id_o)
                                and o_n.id_n IN ({$start_n_string})
                            ) M  
                    JOIN ( SELECT  o.id , o_n.id_n as idA from o,o_n where FIND_WILD_IN_SET(o.id,o_n.id_o)
                            and o_n.id_n IN ({$end_n_string})
                    ) M2 on M.id = M2.id GROUP by id
                ) )  F on F.id = o_rv.id_offre 
    where find_in_set(idD,o_rv.id_n]) < find_in_set(idA,os_rv.id_n)
    )";
```

Comment: Thank you it works ! but how i can fix my env to allow multiple queries in futur ?

Comment: you should check for dbdriver version and also check if laravel allow this feature